# Checking for consecutive True in list Haskell using fold

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell.

For a Project Euler problem, I've generated a list of bools.

```
[True, False, False, True, False. . .True]
```

What I'd like is to write a function find the first four consecutive True's, then return their indices in the list.

Intuitively, I know I should be doing this with a fold and somehow pattern matching. Could you help me? Something like this with a fold? (I have no idea how to retrieve the index of an element.)

```
consecutiveFourTrues (w:x:y:z):xs = if (w && x && y && z) then w else consecutiveFourTrues (x:y:z):xs
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tldr**

`findIndices (\x -> (x == True)) $ map (\x -> all (== True) x) $ sliding 2 bs`

Define a `sliding` function similar to the one found in Scala.

```
sliding :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
sliding size [] = []
sliding size ls@(x:xs) = if length ls >= size then (take size ls) : sliding size xs else sliding size xs
```

Using `sliding 2` with `[True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True]` gives

`[[True,False],[False,False],[False,True],[True,True],[True,False],[False,True],[True,False],[False,True],[True,True]]`

Then we can `map` to see if each sub list is contains `all` `True` values and get the indices of those that do with `findIndices`.

`findIndices (\x -> (x == True)) $ map (\x -> all (== True) x) $ sliding 2 bs`

[3,8]

Comment: I really love how extensible your answer is! :D This would work even if I wanted 385 consecutive False values!

Comment: @DanMaheshwari, I just edited my answer to show how my second approach extends to other numbers as well, as well as refactoring it.

Comment: `(== True)` is just `id`, so it's `findIndices id $ map and $ sliding 2 bs`. Recalculating `length` at each recursive call is ineffecient, I would either define `safeTake :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe [a]` or search for a better approach. `else sliding size xs` is `else []`.

Comment: Using `length` is a really bad idea here -- it makes the algorithm O(n^2). Instead, why not `sliding n = dropLast n . map (take n) . tails`, together with `dropLast n xs = zipWith const xs (drop n xs)`? This is O(n), and, even better, as lazy/productive as you can hope for. Also, `findIndices (\x -> (x == True)) . map (\x -> all (== True) x)` is probably better spelled `findIndices and`.

Comment: @DanielWagner @user3237465 Thanks for the comments especially `id` and `and`. What package is `dropWhile` in?

Comment: @Brian I didn't mention `dropWhile`; perhaps you meant to ask about `dropLast` (which is implemented inline in my comment) or `zipWith` (which is from `Prelude`).

Comment: @DanielWagner @dfeuer Ya, I meant `dropLast`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to zip and then use a specialty fold. First look at each set of four consecutive elements and see if they're all true:

```
import Data.List (zipWith4, findIndex)

consec4 :: [Bool] -> [Bool]
consec4 xs = zipWith4 (\x y z w -> x && y && z && w) xs (drop 1 xs) (drop 2 xs) (drop 3 xs)
```

Now you just need

```
fstConsec4 :: [Bool] -> Maybe Int
fstConsec4 = findIndex id . consec4
```

Now this is not likely to be the very fastest you can do, and it doesn't generalize well to larger windows.

We can instead jump more directly into folds, taking a different approach. Note that this particular version is likely to behave better in GHC 7.10 or later than in earlier versions. I used bang patterns for clarity, but you could use `seq` or `$!` for portability if you like.

Let's start by defining a function conspicuously missing from `Data.List`:

```
{-# INLINE foldrWithIndex #-}
foldrWithIndex :: (Int -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldrWithIndex c n xs = foldr go (`seq` n) xs 0
  where
    go x r !i = c i x (r $ i + 1)
```

Using this function, we can easily define a function that finds the index of the beginning of the first group of `n` consecutive `True` values.

```
consec :: Int -> [Bool] -> Maybe Int
consec n xs = foldrWithIndex go (`seq` Nothing) xs n
  where
    go _ix False r !_ = r n
    go ix True _r 1 = Just (ix - n + 1)
    go _ix True r need = r (need - 1)
```

A quick look at the GHC core this produces suggests it will likely be quite efficient (this was produced using `ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -dno-suppress-type-signatures`):

```
$wconsec :: Int# -> [Bool] -> Maybe Int
$wconsec =
  \ (ww_s1BQ :: Int#) (w_s1BN :: [Bool]) ->
    letrec {
      $wgo_s1BL :: [Bool] -> Int# -> Int# -> Maybe Int
      $wgo_s1BL =
        \ (w1_s1BA :: [Bool]) (ww1_s1BF :: Int#) (ww2_s1BJ :: Int#) ->
          case w1_s1BA of _ {
            [] -> Nothing;
            : y_a1y5 ys_a1y6 ->
              case y_a1y5 of _ {
                False -> $wgo_s1BL ys_a1y6 (+# ww1_s1BF 1) ww_s1BQ;
                True ->
                  case ww2_s1BJ of ds_X16V {
                    __DEFAULT -> $wgo_s1BL ys_a1y6 (+# ww1_s1BF 1) (-# ds_X16V 1);
                    1 -> Just (I# (+# (-# ww1_s1BF ww_s1BQ) 1))
                  }
              }
          }; } in
    $wgo_s1BL w_s1BN 0 ww_s1BQ

consec :: Int -> [Bool] -> Maybe Int
consec =
  \ (w_s1BM :: Int) (w1_s1BN :: [Bool]) ->
    case w_s1BM of _ { I# ww1_s1BQ -> $wconsec ww1_s1BQ w1_s1BN }
```

#### Extreme performance hacking

In theory, it should be possible to do better, especially when looking in long lists. In particular, branching on the `Bool` values may lead to many mis-predicted branches if `True` and `False` values are both frequent. In this case, it's probably better to shove the values into a small bit vector, then play some bitty tricks on it. Unfortunately, it can be tough to convince GHC to do this sort of thing, but I may try later.

Answer (score 2):

Is using `fold` a requirement?
Because otherwise it can be straightforwardly expressed with standard functions from `Data.List`:

```
consec :: Int -> [Bool] -> [Int]
consec n = findIndices (isPrefixOf (replicate n True)) . tails
```

Just read it as English: `findIndices` of all `tails` of the list for which `replicate`-ed `n` times `True` `isPrefixOf`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
consec :: Int -> [Bool] -> [Int]
consec n = findIndices and . foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat []) . take n . tails
```

It's based on ideas from other answers. `take n . tails` returns a matrix, which has lists of consecutive elements of length `<= n` as columns. `foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat [])` transposes the matrix and throws away lists of length `< n`. `findIndices` finds indices.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we should simply count the consecutive `True`s rather than make sublists of them?

```
consec :: Int -> [Bool] -> [Int]
consec m = map (subtract m) . findIndices (>= m) . scanl (\ c x -> if x then c + 1 else 0) 0

ghci> consec 4 [False, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True]
[1,2,7]
```